# One hot representation giving error of index

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to understand one hot representation by the following function. I have printed each and every single line of this function.But I'm getting an error only at the last line that the index is out of bound. I'm unable to understand the reason.How can I fix this problem?

```
def dense_to_one_hot(labels_dense, num_classes):
    num_labels = labels_dense.shape[0]
    index_offset = np.arange(num_labels) * num_classes
    labels_one_hot = np.zeros((num_labels, num_classes))
    labels_one_hot.flat[index_offset + labels_dense.ravel()] = 1
    return labels_one_hot

labels_dense = np.arange(475000)
print labels_dense.shape
num_classes=10
num_labels = labels_dense.shape[0]
print num_labels
index_offset = np.arange(num_labels) * num_classes
print index_offset
print len(index_offset)
print 'index offset is '+str(index_offset.shape)
labels_one_hot = np.zeros((num_labels, num_classes))
print labels_one_hot.shape
x= labels_dense.ravel()
print x
print x.shape
plus= index_offset+x
print plus
print plus.shape
labels_one_hot.flat[plus]=1
```

Answer (score 0):

For the others, the PO was referring to a the example from Tensorflow working with MNIST data, check out the official [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py).

`labels_dense` is a numpy array which is supposed to store elements where each is a class identifier (like 0 represent images labeled as "zero", 9 represents images labeled as "nine").

Here is how the default test data labels look like:

```
In [20]: labels   # same as labels_dense 
Out[20]: array([7, 2, 1, ..., 4, 5, 6], dtype=uint8)
```

In your own code, you generated labels_dense in the right size, but wrong way:

```
In [34]: labels_dense
Out[34]: array([ 0, 1, 2, ..., 474997, 474998, 474999])
```

You see? I am glad your code did not work, otherwise, it might create a 0.5M*0.5 M ~ 50B cells... phew..

The rest of the code is pretty straightforward but I just want to add a bit more intermediate steps to show how `labels_one_hot.flat[index_offset + labels_dense.ravel()] = 1` works. Also, instead of using 475K records, I suggest start using 3 record to prove the idea.

```
In [35]: labels_dense = labels[:3]
In [36]: labels_dense
Out[36]: array([7, 2, 1], dtype=uint8)
In [37]: num_classes = 10
In [38]: num_labels = labels_dense.shape[0]
In [39]: index_offset = np.arange(num_labels) * num_classes
In [40]: index_offset
Out[40]: array([ 0, 10, 20])
In [41]: labels_one_hot = np.zeros((num_labels, num_classes))
In [42]: labels_one_hot
Out[42]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
In [43]: index_offset + labels_dense.ravel()
Out[43]: array([ 7, 12, 21])
In [44]: labels_one_hot.flat[index_offset + labels_dense.ravel()] = 1
In [45]: labels_one_hot
Out[45]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Also, at this stage, your code has nothing to do with Tensorflow at all, if you label your question with numpy or even Python in general, you will get help much faster and probably better.

Reference: [flat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html), [ravel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy.ravel), [arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html), [zeros](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation. Now I got the error in my code that's why my algorithm was giving poor efficiency on both training and test test. Can you please explain explain that how can I convert my label_dense [0,1,  ... 474999] into labels formate that you mentioned. In my code I start labelling from 1 uptil 24, but when I shuffle data both training set and labels. I shuffle their row index as sample.shape[0] that's why I'm getting error.

Comment: @R.ali, I don't think I understand what you want. "how can I convert my label_dense into labels format you mentioned?"

Comment: row = sample.shape[0]
label = np.array([1 for i in range(row)])
for i in range(1,100):  
 k4_label = i+1
 label_file = np.array([k4_label for i in range(row)])
 label= np.append(label,label_file, axis=0)sample.shape[0]==label.shape[0]
shuffled_sample.shape[0] == shuffled_label.shape[0]

Comment: I mean my label range is [0,.... 474999] and in minist label range is [0,....9]. In my code I'm assigning label 1 to 1000 sample and label2 to other 1000 samples. Similarly I assign 24 labels. But when I append then as I mentioned above then num_labels = labels_dense.shape[0] will be 24000. how to fix this problem

Comment: can you please tell me how to map label_dense=[0,1,....474999] into labels[7,2,....4,5,6]

Comment: @R.ali, frankly speaking, I think the answer to that question might be too long to fit into a comment and it is more so a question of how to read the mnist.tar.gz file instead of one hot encoding which I suggest you open up another question.

Comment: can you please tell me how to fix that error? Because labels_dense =array([ 0, 1, 2, ..., 474997, 474998, 474999]) will always start from 0 up to the range of labels. I'm not sure what modification is needed in the code